# mysql_real_escape_string not applying

Tags: php, joomla

I have a form that takes in a number of fields about a camera's details.  This is a custom page I'm creating on Joomla.  First I get the database object:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
```

Process the camera name entered in the form and add to DB:

```
$add_name = $_POST['camera_name'];
$query_insert_camera = "INSERT INTO #__cameras (camera_name, ... , user_id) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($add_name)."', ... ,'".$user->id."')";
$db->setQuery($query_insert_camera);
$db->query();
```

I just get an empty string for camera name.  If I take out `mysql_real_escape_string` it works fine. I'm guessing `mysql_real_escape_string` doesn't like the way I'm establishing a connection...I think.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting a Warning? The docs say it will issue a Warning if it can't find a connection to use. Otherwise I'd recommend you put the connection handle in the function call.

Comment: What kind of connection is `getDBO()` actually using? Is it creating one with `mysql_connect()`, or `mysqli()`, or PDO? What API is being called? `mysql_real_escape_string()` is only available if the connection was established with `mysql_connect()`.

Comment: Why don't you use Joomla's getVar ? http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into JRequest::getVar http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest::getVar

However, it doesn't appear that it can be used in a module: http://groups.google.com/group/joomla-dev-general/browse_thread/thread/15ebde03b858c9e8

Comment: Thanks. How do I see what it has escaped? If I just echo the results I don't actually see it escaping characters.

Comment: I'm still learning myself - when I was struggling with that portion I tried to break it by entering in a ' to see if was escaping or not.  Before using JRequest::getVar it broke, afterward it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across the issue of using mysql(i)_real_escape_string() within Joomla, and found that I needed to pass in the db connection as the first parameter:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$myVar = JRequest::getVar('myVarName');
$mysqlSafeVar = msqli_real_escape_string($db->getConnection(), $myVar);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO #__mytable (' .$db->nameQuote('myField'). ') VALUES (' . $db->quote($mysqlSafeVar) . ')';
$success = $db->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work. I see mysql_real_escape_string() being used *almost* the same way [here](http://code.google.com/p/jcls/source/browse/trunk/com_cls/controller.php?r=31).

The difference between that code, and what you have is minor, but maybe try something like this instead:

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

// Escape the POST var as you grab it
$add_name = mysql_real_escape_string(JRequest::getVar('camera_name', '', 'post', 'string'));

$query_insert_camera = "INSERT INTO #__cameras (camera_name) VALUES ('" . $add_name . "')";
$db->setQuery($query_insert_camera);
$db->query();
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still outputs an empty string.